# Routing Proxmox host additional IP to Ubuntu guest machine

Tags: networking, ubuntu, proxmox

I have an additional IP on my Hetzner server with Proxmox that I want to route it to an Ubuntu guest machine

Here is my network configuration on Host and Guest machine

My guest machine is Ubuntu 18.04

And configurations don't work

My PVE Host net config:

```
# network interface settings; autogenerated

# Please do NOT modify this file directly, unless you know what

# you're doing.

#

# If you want to manage parts of the network configuration manually,

# please utilize the 'source' or 'source-directory' directives to do

# so.

# PVE will preserve these directives, but will NOT read its network

# configuration from sourced files, so do not attempt to move any of

# the PVE managed interfaces into external files!



source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*



auto lo

iface lo inet loopback



auto enp0s31f6

iface enp0s31f6 inet static

        address  77.77.77.241

        netmask  255.255.255.192

        gateway  77.77.77.193

        pointopoint 77.77.77.193

        up route add -net 77.77.77.192 netmask 255.255.255.192 gw 77.77.77.193 dev enp0s31f6

        post-up echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/enp0s31f6/proxy_arp

# route 77.77.77.192/26 via 77.77.77.193



auto vmbr0

iface vmbr0 inet static

  address 77.77.77.241

  netmask 255.255.255.192

  bridge_ports none

  bridge_stp off

  bridge_fd 0

  bridge_maxwait 0

  up route add -host 77.77.77.242 dev vmbr0
```

My Ubuntu VM net config:

```
# This file is generated from information provided by

# the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance.

# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file

# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:

# network: {config: disabled}

network:

    version: 2

    renderer: networkd

    ethernets:

        ens18:

            addresses:

            - 77.77.77.242/26

            dhcp4: no

            dhcp6: no

            gateway4: 77.77.77.193

            routes:

            - to: 0.0.0.0/0

              via: 77.77.77.193

              on-link: true

            nameservers:

                addresses:

                - 8.8.8.8

                - 4.2.2.4
```

I also created a file called /etc/sysctl.d/99-networking.conf and inserted the following contents

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
net.ipv4.conf.enp0s31f6.send_redirects=0
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
```

I cannot use bridged mode since hetzner does not allow multiple MACs on the same external IP, so I have to use routing mode

Comment: Why route? Why not just create another interface on ProxMox and bridge it to the guest VM and set the IP on the Guest VM?

Comment: thanks for your comment. is there any tutorial for this configuration

Comment: Have you read through the Network Configuration Wiki @ https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Network_Configuration ?

Comment: Yes.
I tried network configuration wiki too.
Finally, i used 
[this tutorial](http://sysorchestra.com/proxmox-5-on-hetzner-root-server-with-ipv4)

Comment: I cannot use bridged mode, since hetzner does not allow multiple MACs on same external ip, so I have to use routing mode